# Mix-problem with percentage

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A can is containing coffee and another can is containing exactly the same amount of milk. We take a spoon of coffee and mix it in the milk can. Then we take a spoon from the mix we obtained and mix it in the coffee. Now we have obtain two different mixes, one with some coffee in the milk, and one with some milk in the coffee. Is it more milk in the coffee than it's coffee in the milk or is it the same?

I thought like this: We name the amount in the cans x. Then it lasts x-1 in the coffee-can and the milk-can contains x+1 after the first mix. And then we take $\frac{1}{x+1}$ of this mixture in the coffee-can.

Answer (score 6):

Let each can contain $V$.  You start with $V$ coffee in one can and $V$ milk in the other.  After some spooning (it doesn't matter how much or whether you mix), the coffee can has $c$ coffee and $m=V-c$ milk.  The milk can has $V-m=c$ milk and $V-c$ coffee.  So there is the same amount of coffee in the milk as milk in the coffee.

Comment: The cups having the same ammount of liquid doesn't matter either does it?

Comment: @Ovi:  all that really matters is that each cup ends with the same amount as it started with.  The two amounts could be different.  It seems the problem is always asked with the same amount in each cup.

Comment: Hm interesting whenever I've seen it they never saw this hypothesis. Anyway +1 for opening my eyes to the fact that it doesn't have to be mixed :) I just realized there is a slightly simpler way to solve it though. When you take a spoon from the mixture, you have x spoons of cream in your spoon so you have 1-x spoons of coffe in your spoon. But you also have 1-x spoons of cream in the coffe cup